# Unexpected token in bot.login/storing chat as variable

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a simple bot to re-post a user's input in a specific channel. I have been working on it for a few hours and have gotten stuck here. I am getting a unexpected token error at the bot.login and when i try to fix it, it asks me to put back the part I removed. I also have A general question with my bot. How do you store a users message as a variable? Need this to reprint it and not sure how!

Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // use discord.js
var bot = new Discord.Client(); // sets Discord.Client to bot
const BOT_TOKEN = "hidden_here" 
// bot's token
const PREFIX = "~" // bot's prefix

bot.on("ready", function() { // when the bot starts up, set its game to Use 
*help and tell the console "Booted up!"
//bot.user.setGame("Use ~info") // sets the game the bot is playing
console.log("Bot is now online") // messages the console Bot is now online!
console.log("Use CTRL+C to shut down bot") // messages the console 

});


bot.on("message", function(message) { // when a message is sent
if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return; // if the message is sent by a 
bot, ignore

if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return; // if the message doesn't 
contain PREFIX (*), then ignore

var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "); // removes 
the prefix from the message
var command = args[0].toLowerCase(); // sets the command to lowercase 
(making it incase sensitive)

  if (command == "say") { // creates command say
    if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name)) ) 
return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
    var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
    message.channel.send(sayMessage);
  }

if (command == "vote") { //creates command vote
 if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name)) ) 
return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
    message.channel.send("Type what you would like the vote to be about")
    .then(() => {
    var vote = message.channel.awaitMessages(response)
    message.updateMessage("message", "Great! Starting a vote in #polls now")
    message.channel.goto("#polls")
    message.channel.send(vote)
    message.react('✅');
    message.react('❎');
    });  

  bot.login(BOT_TOKEN); // connects to the bot
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and edited your code. I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure if it's going to work. May I ask that you learn to properly indent your code so that it isn't a struggle for other developers to read; and maybe use a proper IDE like Atom or Visual Studio Code, so you can see syntax errors in your code. Remember to place a semicolon at the end of variable declarations. Also, you don't need to comment on every single line of code, it just creates clutter.

```js
{
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // use discord.js
var bot = new Discord.Client(); // sets Discord.Client to bot
const BOT_TOKEN = "hidden_here";
// bot's token
const PREFIX = "~"; // bot's prefix

bot.on("ready", function() { // when the bot starts up, set its game to Use
    // *help and tell the console "Booted up!"
    //bot.user.setGame("Use ~info") // sets the game the bot is playing
    console.log("Bot is now online") // messages the console Bot is now online!
    console.log("Use CTRL+C to shut down bot") // messages the console
});


bot.on("message", message => { // when a message is sent
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    var command = args[0].toLowerCase();

    if (command == "say") {

        if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name))) {
            message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
            return
        }

        var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
        message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
        message.channel.send(sayMessage);

    }

    if (command === "vote") {

        if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name))) {
            message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
            return
        }

        message.channel.send("Type what you would like the vote to be about")
            .then(() => {
                var vote = message.channel.awaitMessages(response);
                message.updateMessage("message", "Great! Starting a vote in #polls now");
                message.channel.goto("#polls");
                message.channel.send(vote)
                message.react('✅');
                message.react('❎');
            });
    }

});

bot.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```

Also, to store message content, do something like,

```js
var content = message.content;
```

Comment: I attempted to run this code but it is spitting out an error saying that message is not defined! I tried reinstalling discord.js but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is adding to the error you got after running @JeydinNewWon.
You are getting the error "Message is not defined" as it was never defined. To fix this, I will give you the correct line of code that you should replace `bot.on("message", () => {}` with.

```
bot.on('message', async message => {}
```

This defines the Message object that recieved after an event.

If you want the full code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // use discord.js
var bot = new Discord.Client(); // sets Discord.Client to bot
const BOT_TOKEN = "hidden_here";
// bot's token
const PREFIX = "~"; // bot's prefix

bot.on("ready", function() { // when the bot starts up, set its game to Use 
    // *help and tell the console "Booted up!"
    //bot.user.setGame("Use ~info") // sets the game the bot is playing
    console.log("Bot is now online") // messages the console Bot is now online!
    console.log("Use CTRL+C to shut down bot") // messages the console 
});


bot.on('message', async message => { // when a message is sent
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    var command = args[0].toLowerCase();

    if (command == "say") {

        if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name))) {
            message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
            return
        }

        var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
        message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
        message.channel.send(sayMessage);

    }

    if (command === "vote") {

        if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Votebot.Start"].includes(r.name))) {
            message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
            return
        }
    
        message.channel.send("Type what you would like the vote to be about")
            .then(() => {
                var vote = message.channel.awaitMessages(response);
                message.updateMessage("message", "Great! Starting a vote in #polls now");
                message.channel.goto("#polls");
                message.channel.send(vote)
                message.react('✅');
                message.react('❎');
            });
    }

});

bot.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```